# How can I set the first DataGridCell's Background of a selected row in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In WPF DataGrid's template of DataGridCell we can change the Background of selected cell.

But how to change the first cell's background color when a row is selected? Just like what the following picture shows.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your own cell style to highlight each cell background

```
<Window.Resources>    
    <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}">
</DataGrid>
```

Could you please go through the following link

[http://techiethings.blogspot.ch/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html](http://DataGridCell%20Selection)

Comment: Thanks. But I think you do not understand my problem. I mean that in the runtime, when I click one row, datagridrow can change its background of the whole row selected. what I want is to highlight the first **Cell** of this selected Row.

Comment: Hi, I added a link to change cell color. sure it will helps. Default we cant change cell style as your need. we need to iterate Datagrid cell then have to change color.

Comment: Thanks. Is this can be written in xaml directly? I have seen some methods in other's blogs that almost the same with the blog your provider.